# Compare Excel sheets with data in a non-matching rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

The ID column contains all unique values.  Sheet 1 is the master file.  Sheet 2 contains the same IDs, but not necessarily in the same sequence.  I need to identify cases where the Name in Sheet 2 does not match for the same ID on Sheet 1.  I want to do this with highlighting using conditional formatting.

[image]

The second set of tables in the image, labelled "Correct One" shows what I'm trying to achieve.  The names for IDs 11 and 16 don't match, so they are highlighted.

I have tried to use the conditional formula `=A1<>sheet1!A`.  That is checking by cell location rather than by ID, so it incorrectly highlights IDs not in the same sequence.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm working with LO Calc and conditional formatting works a little different.  But the gist is that you need to do a lookup to find the value to compare.  For B2 on sheet2, the conditional test would be something like: value not equal to VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:B6,2,0).  For each cell in the Name column, you are finding its ID in sheet 1 and comparing to the Name value for that ID in sheet 1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57131/discussion-on-question-by-safwan-compare-excel-sheets-with-data-in-a-non-matchin).

Comment: How to put symbol value not equal to,   at start of  vlookup in conditianal test .

Comment: The "not equal to" should be a selection in the conditional formatting wizard, similar to selecting the cell value as what you want to compare.

Comment: You could also select the formula option, where the formula must evaluate to true.  So it would look like: =B2<>VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `'sheet 2'.B3` cell apply `conditional formatting` where value is `not equal` result of `vertical search` function like this:

Libre office syntax

```
VLOOKUP('sheet 2'.$A3;'sheet 1'.$A$3:$B$7;2;0)
```

MS Excel syntax

```
VLOOKUP('sheet 2'!$A3,'sheet 1'!$A$3:$B$7,2,0)
```

with arguments

- SearchCriterion = `'sheet 2'.$A3` - reference to ID value from sheet 2 searched in sheet 1 (absolute column and relative row)
- Array = `'sheet 1'.$A$3:$B$7` - absolute reference to array in sheet 1
- Index = `2` - number of the column in the array that contains the value to be returned
- Sorted = `0` - unsorted

next, use `Format Painter` to copy conditional formatting to other cell in column.